# How pointers allocate memory

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, gets

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

  char *str;

  gets(str);

  puts(str);

return 0;
}
```

output= Segmentation Fault

Why it is giving segmentation fault?

Comment: Pointers do not allocate memory.

Comment: If you want to allocate memory, you need to call `malloc()`

Comment: `str` is just a pointer.  Which area of memory is `str` pointing at?  Don't know?  Neither do I, because you have not initialised it.  It could be pointing anywhere.  You are actually lucky that it crashed.

Comment: advice: read more about pointers

Answer (score 7):

The answer to the question "how pointers allocate memory" is very simple: they don't. That's why you are getting a segmentation fault: accessing data from an uninitialized pointer is *undefined behavior*.

It is programmer who has to allocate memory, and assign it to the pointer. For example, you could use `malloc`:

```
char *str = malloc(10);
fgets(str, 10, stdin);
puts(str);
```

An important thing to note about the above fix is that `fgets` is used instead of deprecated `gets`. This is because `fgets` lets you tell the function how much memory it can use in your buffer, while `gets` assumes that it has all the memory it wants, leading to buffer overruns.

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari You are welcome. If this answers your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that your problem is solved, and earn you a badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

In case of

```
 gets(str);
```

`str` is used uninitialized. Being an automatic local varibale, unless explicitly initialized, the content of `str` is indeterminate. It may point a memory location which is not allocated to your program.

Using (*attempt to write into or even reading from*) uninitiated memory causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault is one of the side effects.

That said, `gets()` is ***pure evil***, because of possible buffer overrun issues. Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a pointer, all you've done is set aside space to store the *address* of another object; you haven't set aside any space for that other object itself.

Here's a hypothetical memory map (addresses are pulled out of thin air and don't represent any real-word architecture, assume 32-bit words):

```
Item        Address        0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----        -------        ----  ----  ----  ----
str         0xfff86400       ??    ??    ??    ??  // ?? represents unknown byte value
```

The *variable* `str` resides at address `0xfff86400`.  Since you declared `str` with `auto` storage duration (that is, within a function) and didn't explicitly initialize it, its value is *indeterminate*; it contains an unknown bit pattern that (most likely) does not correspond to a writable address in your program.  `gets` tries to write data to this *invalid* address, hence the
segfault<sup>1</sup>.  None of the input routines (`fgets`, `scanf`, `fscanf`, `fread`, etc.) will set aside the memory to store the actual input; that's your responsibility.

When you want to manipulate something through a pointer, you need to allocate the thing the pointer points *to*.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
char buf[8] = "blah!";
char *str = buf;
```

This sets aside a buffer to store up to 8 characters, and then assigns the address of the first element of that buffer to `str`, giving us something like this:

```
Item        Address        0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----        -------        ----  ----  ----  ----
buffer      0xfff86400      'b'   'l'   'a'   'h'
            0xfff86404      '!'    00    ??    ??
str         0xfff86408       ff    f8    64    00
```

Similarly, you could use `malloc` to *dynamically* allocate memory for `str` to point to:

```
char *str = malloc( BUF_SIZE );
```

`malloc` sets aside `BUF_SIZE` bytes to store your input string and assigns the pointer to that space to `str`.

---

<sup>1.  Strictly speaking, the behavior on dereferencing an invalid pointer is *undefined*; a segfault is one of *many* possible outcomes.  It could just as easily have clobbered something important such that your program continues to run but now with admin privileges.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate your str first.
Like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  char *str;

  str = malloc(4096);
  gets(str);

  puts(str);

  free(str);
  return (0);
}
```

This will allow to write in str.

For better memory allocation, it could be a good idea to know how much memory you need, instead of arbitrary "4096".

Moreover, don't forget to use free(), when you don't need it anymore.